# Why 22 and 41 can only be in base 7 when it's true that 22 could also be in base 3?

Tags: word-problem

I would like to know how the [solution](http://nrich.maths.org/1131/solution) for this [word problem](http://nrich.maths.org/1131) was attained.I couldn't get why 22 and 41 can only be in base 7 while it's true that 22 could also be in base 3.

Comment: A problem formulation here should be as self-contained as possible, not relying entirely on an external site to supply essential content by linking.  In particular the OP or one of those who responded with Answers should have edited the Question body to include more details of the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that Zios and Zepts have $3$ and $7$ legs.

Therefore, any number of legs that the creatures count needs to be of the form $3a+7b$.

We have that $22_3$ is $8$, but $22_7$ is $16$.

We can express $16$ as $3$ Zios + $1$ Zept, while $8$ cannot be expressed as such.

Therefore, we can effectively rule out counting $8$ legs.

Comment: :Could you tell why the number of legs that the creatures counts need to be of the form $3a + 7b$ . Can it not be either of 3a or of 7b?

Comment: Sure it can! a and b just have to be nonnegative, because we have can't have negative zios and negative zepts. think of it. we can have 10 legs, that would be 1 zio, 1 zept. we can have 6 legs too, that would be 2 zios. but we can't have 2 legs? why? there is no combination of creatures that could have 2 legs in total, right?

Comment: if it is of the form 3a, then it is still of the form 3a+7b, where b=0

Comment: Yes but 3a =8 is impossible and 7b=8 is impossible and 7a+7b =8 is impossible.  It's impossible to count 8 legs.  Ever.

Comment: crippled zio @fleablood

Answer (score 1):

$22$ in base $3$ is $8$ legs...

Comment: :That's true but I can't get why 22 and 41 can only be in base7 when 22 can also be in base 3.

Comment: @justin You can't get $8$ legs by a combination of $3$ and $7$, so the count could not have been done in base $3$, even though $22$ is a possible number in base $3$..

Comment: 41 can't be base 3 because 4 > 3.  The number 8 is impossible no matter what base.  22 base 3 and 11 base 7 are both impossible because 8 is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

$41$ cannot be in base $3$ since only digits in base $3$ are $0,1,2$ not $4$.

Comment: he knows that. he was asking about 22

Comment: @SakethMalyala it was not at all obvious from the question that he know about $41$, he was asking about them both. The $22$ logic is already posted by Michael Brio.